# CAS protocol authentication by cURL without form

Tags: php, curl, cas

I have to access REST APIs that have CAS authentication. Hundreds of requests are launched via a batch on a Windows planned task.

I would like to be able to authenticate with a user and a password stored in a configuration file at each request.

How can I authenticate without going through the authentication form CAS in the background via PHP Rn using CURL?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I authenticate without going through the authentication form CAS in the background via PHP Rn using CURL?

The REST protocol allows one to model applications as users, programmatically acquiring service tickets to authenticate to other applications. Similar to asking for ticket-granting tickets, the following endpoint allows one to only verify the validity of provided credentials as they are extracted from the request body:

```
POST /cas/v1/users HTTP/1.0

username=battags&password=password
```

You may also specify a service parameter to verify whether the authenticated user may be allowed to access the given service. While the above example shows username and password as the provided credentials, you are practically allowed to provide multiple sets and different types of credentials provided CAS is equipped to extract and recognize those from the request body. See this for more info.

A successful response will produce a 200 OK status code along with a JSON representation of the authentication result, which may include the authentication object, authenticated principal along with any captured attributes and/or metadata fetched for the authenticated user.

Please see https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.3.x/protocol/REST-Protocol.html